# Is it a duplicate if someone gave a correct answer in a different question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

In regards to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57047/how-much-is-a-level-20-multiplayer-character-worth-as-a-promoted-war-asset)'s comments, what is the right answer?

Comment: While you may be correct that its not an exact duplicate, that doesn't necessarily make your question a good question. You're basically asking for a piece of trivia that's simply not yet widely known, a more substantive question would ask about how to make these decisions, which probably would give you all the info you need.

Comment: I'm asking a specific question with a specific answer. There are many users out there who know the one, correct answer. As the questioner, I do not know the question hence the asking. The reason I'm asking the question (wanting to know if something's "worth it") is definitely opinion-oriented, but the question itself is not.

Comment: Then your problem is so specific, so localized that its probably not useful to others. However, were you to elaborate on the general choices you have to make for multiplayer characters, it would cover your question and yet be useful to others

Comment: @IvoFlipse Your comments don't make much sense in the context of his specific question. Note that I do agree it should be closed as a dupe, but his question definitely isn't too localized, nor does it have much to do with multiplayer choices, and the answer is definitely useful to others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is basically asking the same thing as the linked question, "Explain to me the functionality of promoting a multiplayer character". In your question, your just asking about it in a different way.

The answer to your question is provided in full in the other question which covers the topic more broadly. Asking a component of the question would just give a component of the answer in the other question. You could copy and paste the other answer for the same result, which is a duplicate.

This is analogous to asking "How does a gun work?" versus "What happens when I pull the trigger of a gun?". You have a bit more understanding of the answer than the original poster, but none-the-less the answer is still the same.

Remember, closed questions are a good thing. They allow different vectors of a question to arrive at the same answer without duplicating and diluting the answer over several iterations. If your duplicate asks it in a unique way, it is a good thing and simply gets closed. If your duplicate asks it in the SAME way, then this is bad and is usually a magnet for downvotes. I don't see any downvotes on your question (yet), in fact you're +2/+0 so far.

Comment: And in this case FAE did the right thing and updated his answer to include the last few bits of info, so there's no reason not to close the other one anymore.

Comment: It happened here too: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54184/how-can-i-defeat-the-cerberus-agents-that-have-physical-shields